# Create a List View with Header sections

Tags: .net, winforms, list, view

I would like to create a 'New Document' dialog similar to the Office 2007 style (see pic).  I am having trouble with the list shown on the left.  I have tried using a ListView control but I can't figure out how to display the header sections that scroll with the list (e.g. 'Template Categories' and 'Microsoft Office Online'

What is my best option for re-creating this style of list??

I am using .net3.5, VS2008 and winforms (NOT WPF).  Am also open to purchasing 3rd party controls if necessary.

[image]
<sub>(source: [com.com](http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/z/200606/office/eb_office2007_024a.png))</sub>

Michael

Comment: Got your pic to show. One of the many nuances of markdown, I suppose - I had to put some text (your sig) *after* the pic for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having seen the pic (did you forget to include it?), I'm guessing you're talking about groups within a ListView. This is pretty easy to accomplish.

Take a look at the MSDN documentation on the [ListView.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups.aspx) property. Once you've defined your groups ("Template Categories" and "Microsoft Office Online" in your example) you can specify a Group on each ListViewItem to make it stay within that group.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I can get the headers working now.  No idea what happened to the pic, it shows when i go into 'edit' mode.. im missing something (stack overflow newb)

Answer (score 0):

I Ended up using a 3rd party control (Elegant.ui.NavigationBar from prof-uis.com) for the final form.  Screenie below.

[My 'New Document' form using Elegant.ui.NavigationBar http://www.ruleclarity.com/images/stories/screenshots/new_document_dialog.jpg](http://www.ruleclarity.com/images/stories/screenshots/new_document_dialog.jpg)

The Headers and items are actually buttons (Elegant.Ui.ToggleButton) with the header buttons disabled so they don't react to the mouse.  This looks ok I think.  Note on this form I have also used a ListView with group headers (in the rightmost pane)